# import strategy within django applications

Tags: python, django, import

I would like to know what is the best import strategy within django reusable applications.

Say I have an application called `usefulapp`. Inside my app, I will need to access, say, the models. Should I use an explicit import as:

```
import usefulapp.models
```

or simply, since I am inside this very app, I could use:

```
import models
```

Which one is recommended?

Are there disadvantages of using the second approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second approach assumes that `.` is in `sys.path` before any other directories that may contain a `models` module. There is no requirement that `.` be in it at all, so importing either via [relative imports](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) or via the app is best.

Answer (score 3):

I personally, try to keep the convention of always importing from the app.

Don't import from the project, because project name can change; your app can be used in some other project (at least you are supposed to make apps like that).

Don't import from `models` directly because, as Ignacio rightly mentions, it is not necessary that `.` is in the python path.

But, App names are always on the python path. Django adds them to the python path (via `set_environ(settings)`), on the top of the list, so you can be rest assured that the right files are always picked up.